# Weight painting in small spaces

Tags: weight-painting, weight-paint-mode

can I get some ideas on how I can get into small spaces like this while weight painting? The biggest issue is the head and collar weights blending together, as shown here:
[image]

Changing weight, radius, and strength don't really help. I've attempted removing the collar and head to get under it, but this complicates other things.

Comment: Use vertex mode in weight painting.  Toggle into edit mode and hide all verts you don't want to see or paint.  Toggle back into weight paint mode.  Paint.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add particles only to the head but you can't reach some vertices you have to separate objects. In this way, you could work with the head only and after weight paint, you can join it back to the collar if you want. For this select collar first, then head with particles and join. After this, the collar will have particles too, but with 0 weight.
But working with separate objects is much easier anyway especially if you want to do weight paint/add particles to other elements.